# Which test for fold changes (where controls are always 1)

Tags: statistical-significance, ratio

I have some data, where I have 3 separate biological groups which grow at different rates. If I treat them all with X, I see an increase in growth. If I look at the absolute numbers then there is very high variability due to the basal difference, but if I do a fold change against the control to remove this factor I see a similar effect e.g. 20% increase in growth in all 3. Is there a way to statistically test this? I've had t-test (or rather ANOVA+bonferroni, as I actually have compound x and y as well as the control) suggested but I'm not convinced this is correct as by doing the fold change all of my controls are "1". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation and your data? Do you have repeated measures? What are your variables? Etc.

Comment: @gung It's with cell lines, so not technically repeated measures. Only variables are +/- the compounds of interest and the 3 cell lines used (which are biological replicates, again the only difference is that they grow faster and we're not interested in this as we've already separately assessed it). So the data is essentially
Cell line 1/2/3, control, comp X, comp Y - 9 numbers.
I could of course pile in the repeats to analyse each cell line separately but as they show the same effect when you normalise for the known difference I'm hoping this isn't necessary.

Comment: How do you know a cell grew faster than another unless you measured both beforehand & later on? What kind of measures are you using, mass, something else?

Comment: @gung We have previously measured numbers of cells for each line across 6 day growth curves multiple times so we know this is consistent. The control conditions in the recent expt match up to this. The same number of cells was used to set up the experiments and counted after treatment. So in the faster cell population there is more cells in the control than in the control of slow cells. But there are even more in the treatments for each compared to control. Hopefully that makes more sense? Been looking and think mann-whitney I test might be acceptable under this circumstance?